# Django select model fields through in meta class

Tags: python, django, model

Here I need to choose user's first name and second name from another table. Model is StockTransfer but I need from Users model

```
class Meta:
    model = StockTransfer
    fields = (
        'id', 'from_stock', 'to_stock',
        'comment', 'products',
        'status', 'user',
        'transfer_request',
        'created_date',
        'date_delivery',
        'modified_date',
        'accepted_time',
        'cancelled_time',
        'first__name',
        'second__name'

    )
```

model (**users.py**)

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

----- stocktransfer.py (model)

```
class StockTransfer(BaseModel, DeleteMixin):
PENDING = '0'
APPROVED = '1'
CANCELLED = '2'

STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (PENDING, 'pending'),
    (APPROVED, 'approved'),
    (CANCELLED, 'cancelled'),
)

from_stock = models.ForeignKey('main.Stock', related_name='from_transfers')
to_stock = models.ForeignKey('main.Stock', related_name='to_transfers')
comment = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=PENDING)
user = models.ForeignKey('main.User', null=True)
```

I think I can choose the first name and second name just simple way write first_name and second_name in metaclass fields. Is it right?
Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly are you asking about?

Comment: i want to choose user's first name and second name  through user's table in meta class. But in meta class another model

Comment: I don't really understand.. Do you want to display a select box where you can choose a user ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that stock_transfer is an instance of StockTransfer:

```
stock_transfer = StockTransfer.objects.all().get(id=1)
first_name = stock_transfer.user.first_name
second_name = stock_transfer.user.second_name
```

Comment: i don't think so. In meta class is StockTransfer but i need fields from User table

Comment: Your StockTransfer class has a field user so you can use it to read it trough the .user.